# How to scroll down by certain amount of pixels below a container with an id?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have something like this when an event is triggered :

```
window.location.href = "#my-elm";
```

And I have a div that has that id, when the event is triggered my window is scolling to the div position of course, but I have a fixed header on top in the page of about 150px in height , so part of my div is not visible..

What I want to do is when my event is triggered I will scroll down to the anchor position + 150 px

I tried to add this on my page, what I understand is this is going to watch my hash haching ( my anchors changing ?? ), & this will scroll an extra 150 px, but did not work

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 150);
});
```

Any ideas ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT :**

The answer provided is correct for Firefox, Edge, Chrome, Opera, Safari +11

For Safari -11 this won't work, it will work only for the latest versions, which is bad, you have to implement an other solution to fix the Safari BUG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with CSS only.

Add a [`scroll-margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top) to the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector like this:

```
:target {
 scroll-margin-top: 150px;
}
```

It will add a margin from the top edge of the scroll container for every anchor element, if you want to apply it just for `#my-elm` for some reason, change the selector from `:target` to `#my-elm`

Comment: Working for all browsers but not working for some Safari versions !

Comment: yeah there is a bug in Safari on this https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189265 it looks like it has been fixed in latest version

Comment: Yes, Many of my users are uses Safari, our client uses safari a lot for debugging, your answser is correct but not working for all browsers!

Comment: I don't have an old Safari to test now but can you try `scroll-snap-margin-top`?